# Remove WHERE condition when subquery does not return any row

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I'm writing a complex MySQL query and I'm having trouble figuring out how to finish it.

Here's the part that's giving me trouble (it's only a part of my query):

```
SELECT * FROM table AS t1
WHERE date < (
    SELECT date FROM table AS t2 
    WHERE phase="B" AND t2.target = t1.target
)
```

Basically, I have items, each one with a date, a phase (A,B,C) and a target. For a target, there are several items of type A, then an **single** and **optional** item of type B, then items with type C.

For each target, I want to select all the rows following these conditions:

1. If there is an item with phase "B" (lets call him *itemX*), I want to return all items with a date inferior to the date of *itemX*
2. If there is no item with phase "B", I want to return all rows

The date parameter is very important. In most cases, the 3 phases are distinct, and cannot overlap, but there are some cases in which that happens.

The problem here, is that my subquery does not return any rows in case 1, and a single cell in case 2.

If we are in case 1, the whole condition `WHERE date < (...)` is irrelevant and should not be applied in the query.

I tried several possibilities with `IFNULL` and `EXISTS`, but I think I did it wrong because I keep getting syntax errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  m.*
FROM    (
        SELECT  target, MAX(date) AS maxdate
        FROM    mytable
        ) md
JOIN    mytable m
ON      m.target = md.target
        AND m.date <
        COALESCE
        (
        (
        SELECT  date
        FROM    mytable mb
        WHERE   mb.target = md.target
                AND mb.phase = 'B'
        ORDER BY
                mb.target, pmb.phase, mb.date
        LIMIT 1
        ),
        maxdate + INTERVAL 1 SECOND
        )
```

Create two indexes:

```
mytable (target, date)
mytable (target, phase, date)
```

for this to work fast.

Answer (score 1):

You might try

```
SELECT * FROM table AS t1
left join 
table as t2 
on t1.Target = t2.Target
and t2.phase="B"
where t2.target is null OR 
OR t1.date < t2.Date
```

Comment: I don't understand the `t2.target is null` part. Can you explain please ?

Comment: By doing a left join you are including all rows on the left side of the join, and only matching rows from the right side of the join. Assuming a left side table t1, and right side table t2, in cases where the join condition is not met the value of any column in t2 will be be null. Since the goal in this case is to omit the where clause if our join condition is not met (targets match and the t2 phase value is 'B') we first check to see if the join condition failed, if so we return a row.

Comment: If the join condition succeeds, we return a row if it is the case that the t1 date value is less than the t2 date value. Since t2.Target is part of our join condition, it will only be null in cases where there was no match.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps

```
SELECT *
FROM table AS t1
LEFT JOIN table AS t2 ON t2.target = t1.target AND (t1.date < t2.date)
WHERE (phase = 'B')
```

I'm assuming the `table` in your query is actually two tables and you're not doing a self join? If so, then you'll have to specify which table's `phase` you're referring to.

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted is called "One subquery per condition anti-pattern". Use the CASE-WHEN-THEN.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.*
  FROM table t1
  LEFT
  JOIN ( SELECT t.target
              , MIN(t.date) AS b_date
           FROM table t
          WHERE t.phase = 'B'
          GROUP BY t.target
       ) t2
    ON t1.target = t2.target AND t1.date < t2.b_date
```

If there is some guarantee that a given target will have no more than one row with "phase"='B' at most, you can get by without the MIN and GROUP BY, like this:

```
SELECT t1.*
  FROM table t1
  LEFT
  JOIN ( SELECT t.target
              , t.date AS b_date
           FROM table t
          WHERE t.phase = 'B'
       ) t2
    ON t1.target = t2.target AND t1.date < t2.b_date
```